# Activating Material Theme Through Package Control

Tags: json, sublimetext, package-control

I've installed the Material Theme through Package Control for Sublime Text. I'm following the install and activation instructions found here: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Material%20Theme

However, when I get to the Activation part, I can't figure out how to properly insert the JSON code into the (Preferences > Setting - User) file.

I've been copying and pasting the code into the file, but it throws the error:

> Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:6:1

Any help is appreciated.

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
["theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme", 
"color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme",]
}
```

Comment: The JSON is invalid. This may help you: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank you!!! That helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer:

```
{
        "ignored_packages": [
            "Vintage"
        ],

        "theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme",
        "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme"
    }
```